# Challenged accessing containerized DNS-SD

Tags: docker, dbus, avahi

I'm a ZeroConf (and Rust) noob and I'm struggling to understand why I'm unable to access a service based upon the [`astro-dnssd`](https://crates.io/crates/astro-dnssd) example when the code is containerized **and** run in a subshell.

The following work:

1. Running the binary and `avahi-browse` on the host:

```sh
./server
```

Yields:

```sh
avahi-browse -all
+ enp5s0 IPv6 asto-dnssd                                    _rust._tcp           local
```

2. Running the binary in the container manually and `avahi-browse` on the host:

```sh
docker run .... --entrypoint=bash [[image]]
> service dbus start
> service avahi-daemon start
> ./service
```

And:

```sh
+ docker0 IPv4 asto-dnssd                                    _rust._tcp           local
```

3. Running the binary in a subshell after starting `dbus` and `avahi-daemon`:

```sh
docker run .... --entrypoint=bash [[image]]
> service dbus start
> service avahi-daemon start
> bash -c "./service"
```

But, if I start the services in the subshell **and** run the binary, nothing:

```sh
docker run .... --entrypoint=bash [[image]]
> bash -c "service dbus start && service avahi-daemon start && ./service"
```

Why would this be?

I have another example using the [`zeronconf`](https://crates.io/crates/zeroconf) crate and this works fine this way.

IIUC I must start `dbus` and `avahi-daemon` in the container image **before** the server and using a subshell is the correct (!?) approach:

```
ARG PROJECT=astro-dnssd

FROM rustlang/rust:nightly-slim as builder

ARG PROJECT

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev

RUN USER=root cargo new --bin ${PROJECT}

WORKDIR /${PROJECT}

COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml
RUN cargo build --release
RUN rm src/*.rs

ADD . ./

# Replace hyphens with underscores in ${PROJECT}
RUN rm ./target/release/deps/$(echo ${PROJECT} | tr '-' '_')*

RUN cargo build --release


FROM debian:buster-slim as runtime

ARG PROJECT

WORKDIR /bin

# Copy from builder and rename to 'server'
COPY --from=builder /${PROJECT}/target/release/${PROJECT} ./server

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y \
    libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/dbus

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "service dbus start && service avahi-daemon start && ./server"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: timing.

If I add a `sleep` between the service starting, this appears to give the system time to work correctly:

This doesn't work:

```sh
(
  service dbus start
  service avahi-daemon start
  /release/astro-dnssd
)
```

But this does:

```sh
(
  service dbus start
  service avahi-daemon start
  sleep 2s
  /release/astro-dnssd
)
```